# is there any C library available that contains APIs for ifconfig?

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I want to set the MTU in or to get some device details, but I don't want to use
system("ifconfig ...").

Is there any way to do it in C? Some like libifconfig.so?

The source code of MTU can be found [here](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/sbin/ifconfig/ifconfig.c?rev=1.169&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup).

But I really don't too much time right now. How can I get the name of ALL the available interfaces (I have plenty in my system)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with `ioctl`. See `netdevice(7)`. I'm guessing `SIOCGIFMTU` and `SIOCSIFMTU` are what you're looking for. I don't know if it's standard, update your question if you need to support other Unixes.

**EDIT**

To get the interfaces on your machine (untested):

```
int sock;
struct ifconf *conf;

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFCONF , (char*) conf);
```

Don't be sloppy and don't forget to check the return values. I don't check them here because I don't care; you probably do.

Comment: getifaddrs on Linux also appropriate for understanding the MTU on a NIC.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are ways to do it in C. Ask yourself what ifconfig is written in?

Since Linux is open source, you can download the source code for ifconfig and look at the APIs that it uses. That is the easiest method in my opinion.

If I feel like looking at the code myself, I may later edit this to include the APIs.

Comment: Sensible, but more of a comment really.

Comment: I answered the question that was asked in the title. If that was not the question then it needed a better title.

Answer (score 1):

`if_nameindex` is the function to get a list of all interfaces.

Actually doing much with them relies on system-specific `ioctl` calls.

Honestly, your best bet, rather than wasting your time obtaining and reading 100x over-complicated legacy sources of `ifconfig`, etc., is to just run `strace ifconfig ...` and look at what `ioctl` syscalls it's making. Actually, this is a great general approach to replicating behavior from programs which have overly complicated source logic or for which you don't have the source.

Answer (score 0):

On my debian box I can

```
sudo apt-get install iproute{,-dev,-doc}
sudo apt-get build-dep iproute
apt-get source iproute --compile
```

That will give me the source to `ip` (the new ifconfig), the documentation and the development header for building iproute extensions. Oh and the source will have been compiled :)

Access the documentation via `/usr/share/doc/iproute-do` (the `examples/` looks interesting).